# How to properly use $ inside functions / self invoking, that are part of a noConflict process via jQuery?

Tags: jquery

With the following code, I would like to use $ inside of function declarations, that are then referenced inside of a self invoking function.  How can I do this process when using noConflict()?  When I run the following code I get "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function"

```
//I have jQuery 2.2.4 linked at the bottom of my page like this...

//<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

//then my code...

var jq224 = $.noConflict();

function dosomething(){
$("#wrapper").append('<p>connect me</p>');
}

function doanotherthing(){
$("#someid").append('<p>show me something more</p>');
}

(function($) { 
  dosomething();
  doanotherthing();
}(jq224));
```

Why does the above process throw an error? But if I do the following, it does not throw an error...

```
  (function($) { 
     $("#wrapper").append('<p>connect me</p>');
    }(jq224));
```

Comment: Where is `var jq224 = $.noConflict();` in the code called? Most likely jquery has not loaded by the time this is called. You say its included in the bottom of the page so if `$.noConflict()` is declared prior to jQuery being included you will see the error you are seeing.

Comment: I wrote it in a comment in my original question above - I have it linked above that JavaScript code.  Let me add it as I have it in comment form...

Comment: Yes sorry, just reread it and saw that. If its included below the declaration of this code then the noConflict call is happening before jQuery loads.

Comment: Thanks, the script link to jQuery 2.2.4 is attached before the declaration...which is why I am puzzled in why I am getting an error.

Comment: Also noConflict releases the `$` variable. So you can no longer use it anymore. You need to reference jQuery using `jq224` or `jQuery`. https://jsfiddle.net/ewxbe8ch/

Comment: ahhhh!!! thank you so much for clarifying that!  I didn't know that little bit of advice.  So I should still keep (function($)... even though $ is no longer usable from this point?

Comment: No its not needed and not defined anymore anyway. Well you can still use it, you are just defining it at a new scope since you pass j224 into the function.

Comment: If yo write up a demo, that would be helpful.  I'm trying to do what you are saying but still getting an error.  thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand. Check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/bkxf5td4/ You don't need to pass it in. And if you do those functions no longer are in scope. So you need to do this if you want to continue using $: https://jsfiddle.net/bkxf5td4/1/ Honestly there are so many ways to make this work. Would be hard to list all the possibilities out. =]

Comment: That helps - thank you!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you call `noConflict` the "previous" reference of `$` is restored. Since `$` was not previously declared, it's now unknown.

You can however pass `$` to the functions you're calling:

```js
var jq224 = $.noConflict();

function dosomething($) {
  $("#wrapper").append('<p>connect me</p>');
}

function doanotherthing($) {
  $("#someid").append('<p>show me something more</p>');
}

(function($) {
  dosomething($);
  doanotherthing($);
}(jq224));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='wrapper'>wrapper</div>
<div id='someid'>someid</div>
```

Comment: ah, I also see now I can pass whatever I want, just as long as I am consistent with passing it down from the self invoking function to the declarations.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you've set jQuery as `noConflict` and then you are trying to access the `$` inside your two methods

```
function dosomething(){
    $("#wrapper").append('<p>connect me</p>');
}

function doanotherthing(){
    $("#someid").append('<p>show me something more</p>');
}
```

at this time `$` is no longer associated with jQuery, for example because you also have the Microsoft.Ajax js files that use `$` character, so you can either use it as

```
function dosomething(){
  jq224("#wrapper").append('<p>connect me</p>');
}

function doanotherthing(){
   jq224("#someid").append('<p>show me something more</p>');
}
```

or using immediately invoked function

```
(function($) { 
     // in this function scope $ is 'just' one of the parameters that has been set as jq224
     $("#wrapper").append('<p>connect me</p>');
}(jq224));
```

Comment: Thank you @nizzik, So if I was to go with the latter approach, I would have to create multiple immediately invoked functions for readability purposes of various function actions?